# type parameters and upper type bounds

Tags: scala, types

Can't figure out why this does not work:

```
def f[A: Double](x: A) = x / 4 // error: "Double does not take type parameters"

println(f(87.7))
```

While this one works:

```
def f[A <: Double](x: A) = x / 4

println(f(87.7))
```

The only difference is that in the first case I just specify particular type, and in the second I define type upper bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `[A: Double]` is not a correct way to define a type parameter. This form is applicable to define a <strike>class manifest</strike> *context bound* (new in Scala 2.8 - thanks @mhs for the link); however, the `ClassManifest[T]` type used to represent context bounds is a parameterized type, so `Double` is not fit as a class manifest.

Note though that context bounds and manifests were introduced to solve the problem of generic array creation, so there is no point using one here, as your function  - as it is shown above - has nothing to do with arrays.

Comment: A context bound has nothing to do with manifests. It is the other way: manifests can be used in context bounds. In the question, there are no manifests used, nor are they expected there. The asker only mixed their syntax with type ascription.

Answer (score 2):

When a formal type parameter has the form of the one in this definition:

```
def floob[Glorp : Fleeb](arg1: Glorp): Swish = ...
```

... it is merely syntactic sugar for this definition:

```
def floob[Glorp](arg1: Glorp)(implicit i1: Fleeb[Glorp]): Swish = ...
```

This is called a *context bound*.

This explains why you're getting a diagnostic about `Double` not taking type parameters.

Because this use of the single colon is entirely unrelated the one used in type annotations and type ascriptions, I uniformly write context bounds with a space on both sides of the colon and never write type annotations or type ascriptions with a space on the left (except when required, when the name to the left is punctuation rather than alphanumeric).